# Unable to resolve class AsyncHttpBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy

Using **Grails 1.3.9**

**buildConfig.groovy**

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:async-http-builder"
```

code:

```
    AsyncHttpBuilder client = new AsyncHttpBuilder()
    Promise<HttpClientResponse> p = client.post("http://someuUrl") {
        contentType 'application/json'
        json {
            receiver number
            message content
            sender sender
        }
    }
    p.onComplete { HttpClientResponse resp ->
        println(resp);
    }
```

I get the error in the topic title. What am I missing here?

Comment: Really version 1.3.9?

Comment: Sadly yes, very old project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather general steps for checking problems with missing plugins

1. Check if you have mavenRepo `"https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"` in `repositories {` in BuildConfig.groovy
2. Provide plugin version, so instead of `"org.grails.plugins:async-http-builder"` try `"org.grails.plugins:async-http-builder:1.0.0"`
3. Try `grails refresh-dependencies` in the terminal

Looking at the commit dates, it looks like a fresh plugin (<1 year old), so it's possible it works only with newer Grails versions (2+/3+).

The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-http/snapshot/) states

> Note that this client does not require Grails itself, and can easily be used standalone or as an independent HTTP client.
>   (...)
>
> To get started with the HTTP client you should declare a dependency on the grails-http-client project in your build.gradle file:
>
> `compile "org.grails:http-client:VERSION"`

So I would probably just try that, as the plugin might not play well with your old Grails version.

Comment: @Jacob and can you find it here? https://grails.org/plugins/

The plugins for Grails 1/2 can be different than the ones for Grails 3+, and they do have a separate site.

I will update my answer in a minute

Comment: Looks like you are right I completely missed the fact this is only a grails3 plugin. Anyway trying do to a async request I am completely blocked by the old Grails. Even the Promise classes are not supported.